# How to keep the text color black when the toolstrip menu is disabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, toolstrip

When a toolstrip menu is not enabled, its text color turns into grey. Is there any way to keep it black? Or any other color?

Already tried with ForeColor but it only makes a difference when the menu is enabled.

Comment: I take it this is Winforms? WPF you would just override the control tempalte

Comment: Yes, it is a win form. Could you be more specific? How can I override the templates?

Comment: I don't know if you can in winforms. WPF gives you a lot more control over the UI styling (especially in instances like this). Hopefully someone else can help!

Comment: @IoanV - You misunderstood what he said.  In _WPF_ you would override the control template, **not** in `Winforms`.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for your suggestion, next time it'll be a WPF.

Comment: Why would you change something that is standard in Windows and thus change the way people are expecting your application to behave?

Comment: @Brandon shame it doesn't work in win forms.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie, because I want a toolstrip menu to be unclickable, and therefore I thought of making it disabled and still remain black-colored because it looks better.

Comment: figured it out, thanks guys. if there is any way to upvote you/your comments tell me. (i'm new here)

Comment: @IoanV - You can simply just post what you did as your answer and then accept it.  In fact, if you do that, I will up vote it since you solved your problem and will get a reputation boost.

Comment: @Brandon  "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 6/4/2014 3:05:33 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." meh ... gonna answer it tomorrow then. btw thanks for your answers

Comment: How many items do you have on your toolstrip? A possible *naive* solution would be to declare a variable that indicates if the toolstrip is disabled or not and in every click handler to exit if the control is disabled. This way your items are normal, but wont work and are controlled from one entry point.

Comment: For the record, @PeterRitchie has it right.  Don't do it.  It's that way for a reason...it's expected behavior for an application to visually describe the unresponsive nature of the control.  You're damning your users to mashing the mouse button wondering why your control is broken and doesn't respond.

Answer (score -1):

For the record, I agree with both @PeterRitchie and @DonBoitnott. Just don't do it. And I saw in your comments where you already answered your own question, but you have not posted your answer and accepted it here on SO.

So, in order to accomplish this with WinForms, you'll need to do Custom Drawing of your control in order to override the standard, default behavior of Windows with regards to these UI elements.

Again, I know you said you already accomplished this, but please, do the rest of your users a  favor and don't do it. It may look good to you, but the changing the text to gray when the toolbar is disabled gives users a cue about what they can/can't do with your application in a given state.

Comment: Why the down vote? Any constructive criticism would be appreciated to improve the content of this answer.